# Create an in-game TextBox

Tags: c#, monogame

So I am trying to implement username system into my game and to do so I need to let the user input their desired username. I created a `TextBox` class.

**EDIT**

Upon making a further research on other people's experience with the creation of a `TextBox` in-game, and their approach I came to the following conclusions:

- My current code is badly designed because the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys` and `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.KeyboardState.GetState()` were never supposed to be used like this.
- Because of that, the code is inefficient and would consume huge time and effort to do things that are otherwise insignificant because Windows handles them for you, when using `Winforms`. I will try to find a possible solution by working with some Win32 functions from the `user32.dll`. And probably use `regexp` to validate strings.

Once I have it figured out, I'm going to revisit the current code and see what I can recycle and then, scrap the rest.

Comment: By the way, `nameField.OnFocus += NameField_OnFocus;` is called on every `Update()` call. You can subscribe to an event more than once: in this case, that happens up to 60(?) times per second, and `NameField_OnFocus` will be called the corresponding number of times - easily thousands. You should set the event handler only once, preferably in `LoadContent`.

Comment: But then there will be no way for me to check if the mouse is in the rectangle and if it was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the input problem is here:

```
if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(keys))
{
    keys = MainGame.InputManager.PressedKeys;
```

If I understand correctly, this literally reads "if any of the keys pressed last frame is pressed, then do check for input", which is always false. Removing the `if` statement should solve the problem in that case.

I don't quite follow how the `StringBuilder` is used. `StringBuilder` is meant for string modification with low garbage generation, but you're negating that by calling `ToString` and updating a duplicate string on every key press. Also, if the string length exceeds maximum length, you're truncating the displayed `final` string but not `content`, getting them out of sync. I'd just go with modifying `final` directly.

Detecting alphanumeric characters is easiest done with [`char.IsLetterOrDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also look into [`GameWindow.OnTextInput`](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=M_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_GameWindow_OnTextInput) if you want to replicate WinForms behavior.

Comment: How can I access `GameWindow Window` outside of the `Game` class without having to create a new instance of the `Game`? Also by removing the `if` and using a `string` instead of `StringBuilder`, when I press a key it gets drawn 5 times, as if I'm holding it but I'm not.

Comment: You can pass the window as a parameter, or otherwise hook up the event. That is up to your engine design.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately obvious with the code, so a couple guesses: Do you assign `prevKeyboardState` correctly? Is `TextBox.Update` somehow called more often than `InputManager` updated?

Comment: In `InputManager.Update()` I assign `prevKeyboardstate` like this: `prevKeyboardState = currKeyboardState;`.